# How to use WebPage as a desktop wallpaper in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

The active desktop was supported to some versions of IE and in Xp.
I want to use a webpage from any site to be my wall paper.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

With [Snippage](http://snippage.gabocorp.com/) you can create widgets from sites.